# Subscribe user to a plan using Stripe, Google Cloud Functions and Swift works, but

Tags: javascript, swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have implemented the following solution to subscribe a user to a plan which works 99% of the time. The problem is that from time-to-time the app displays an error message even though the user has been successfully subscribed.

The process flow goes as follows:

1. The user taps subscribe in the app, which it thens writes the following values to Firebase

[image: ![enter image description here]

2. Using the following deployed Google Cloud Functions I then subscribe/un-subscribe the user to a plan based on the written value for **`subscriptionTriggered`** above. The response from `Stripe` is written back to `Firebase` which also contains a key **`status`**

[image]

.

```
exports.subscribeCustomer = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/subscription/subscriptionTriggered')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

      const subscriptionTriggered = change.after.val();

      if (subscriptionTriggered === true) {

        console.log('subscriptionTriggered: ', subscriptionTriggered);

        // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
        return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.params.userId}/customer_id`)
            .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
              return snapshot.val();
            }).then((customer) => {
              return admin.database().ref('/app-config/stripePlan').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                const plan = snapshot.val();
                return  stripe.subscriptions.create({
                    customer: customer,
                    items: [
                      {
                        plan: plan,
                      },
                    ]
                  });
              });
            }).then((response) => {
              // If the result is successful, write it back to the database
              return change.after.ref.parent.child('response').set(response);
              //return snap.ref.child('response').set(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
              // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
              // still logging an exception with StackDriver
              return change.after.ref.parent.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
            }).then((error) => {
              return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
            });


      } else if (subscriptionTriggered === false) {

        console.log('subscriptionTriggered: ', subscriptionTriggered);

        return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.params.userId}/subscription/response/id`)
          .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            return snapshot.val();
          }).then((sub) => {
            return stripe.subscriptions.del(
              sub
            );
          }).then((response) => {
            // If the result is successful, write it back to the database
            return change.after.ref.parent.child('response').set(response);
            //return snap.ref.child('response').set(response);
          }).catch((error) => {
            // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
            // still logging an exception with StackDriver
            return change.after.ref.parent.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
          }).then((error) => {
            return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
          });

      }//end else-if

});
```

3. **The app then waits for 5 seconds** and then reads the written response **`status`** key. And will either load the next view or display an error message. The issue is that there are times when the error message has been displayed even though when I check the response on `Firebase` manually the **`status`** key is **`active`** which it should then process accordingly.

I have a feeling that the network has taken longer than 5 seconds to write to `Firebase` therefore returning **`status = canceled`** instead. **Is there another way I can check the subscription status instead of simply increasing the wait time from 5 seconds to a longer wait to cater for network delays?**

.

```
func checkSubscriptionIfSuccessfulAndAction(){

        guard let discoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscoverVC") as? DiscoverVC else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(5000)) {

            DataService.run.checkUserHasActiveSubscription(handler: { (status) in

                print("inside checkSubscriptionIfSuccessfulAndAction status: \(status)")

                if status == "active" {

                    //Subscription was processed successfully and is active
                    print("Customer Subscribed successfully to view Carousel")

                    DataService.run.getLatestSubscriptionAndPaymentSourceStatus()

                    Utilities.run.dismissSVHUD(delay: 0.0)

                    discoverVC.initData(forVenue: self.venue!)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        self.presentDetail(discoverVC)

                    }//end DispatchQueue.main.async


                } else {

                    // There was an error Subscribing the customer

                    print("There was an error processing the charge by Stripe and it returned an error message")
                    Utilities.run.dismissSVHUD(delay: 1.0)

                    self.showMessageViaNotificationBannerSwift(message: "oops! We hit a snag, please try again!")

                }//end if-else

            })//end checkUserHasActiveSubscription

        }//end DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter

    }//end func
```

Comment: You've got a bit of a callback hell situation going on there. I'd try and extract a lot of that JS logic into separate functions to make debugging easier. Creating a subscription on Stripe shouldn't take 5 seconds, so there's definitely something else going on here.

Comment: thanks @PaulAsjes my JS function logic is quiet simple I believe and I don't know how breaking it up any further will help, it either subscribes or un-subscribes if the value written is `true` or `false`. My issue is not so much that it takes long to subscribe, like I said 99% of the time this works perfectly.  The 1% of the time when it doesn't my only observation has been when Firebase has been "idle" (nothing been written for sometime) and perhaps the read of the response is delayed for some reason.